# October CMS Query Builder can't get relation model

Tags: eloquent, query-builder, relation, octobercms, laravel-query-builder

Can anyone explain this behavior?

In example, two models:

People, Country

People belongsTo Country:

```
public $belongsTo = [                                                                                                                                                                                          
    'country' => [                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        'Test\TestPlugin\Models\Country',                                                                                                                                                                          
    ]
```

I created an entries of each model, and associate it.

There is tinker dump:

```
>>> Test\TestPlugin\Models\People::all();                                                                                                                                                                          
=> October\Rain\Database\Collection {#926                                                                                                                                                                          
     all: [                                                                                                                                                                                                        
       Test\Testplugin\Models\People {#928                                                                                                                                                                         
         id: 1,                                                                                                                                                                                                    
         country_id: 1,                                                                                                                                                                                            
       },                                                                                                                                                                                                          
       Test\Testplugin\Models\People {#930                                                                                                                                                                         
         id: 2,                                                                                                                                                                                                    
         country_id: 0,                                                                                                                                                                                            
       },                                                                                                                                                                                                          
     ],                                                                                                                                                                                                            
   }     

>>> Test\TestPlugin\Models\People::with('country')->get();                                                                                                                                                         
=> October\Rain\Database\Collection {#963
     all: [
       Test\Testplugin\Models\People {#943
         id: 1,
         country_id: 1,
         country: Test\Testplugin\Models\Country {#965
           id: 1,
           name: "Russia",
         },                                                                                                                                                                                                        
       },                                                                                                                                                                                                          
       Test\Testplugin\Models\People {#945
         id: 2,
         country_id: 0,
         country: null,
       },                                                                                                                                                                                                          
     ],                                                                                                                                                                                                            
   }
```

I see that People#1 has relation with Country#1, but when I try to get this relation in query builder, it return empty collection:

```
>>> Test\TestPlugin\Models\People::country()->get();                                                                                                                                                               
=> October\Rain\Database\Collection {#970
     all: [],
   }                                                                                                                                                                                                               
>>>
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

You should first get the People model and then you can get Country for the specific model.

Something like this:

```
$people = Test\TestPlugin\Models\People::all();
foreach ($people as $person){
    $country = $person->country;
    # do something with the country
}
```

PS. `$person->country` returns the country model and `$person->country()` returns the query builder object

Comment: I'm look for method, not dynamic properties. My mistake is I try to apply method to many entries. I must get one entry and then call method, like this:
Test\TestPlugin\Models\People::find(1)->country()->get();

Answer (score 0):

Instead to call relation method on entire model, first need to select one entry:

```
Test\TestPlugin\Models\People::find(1)->country()->get();
```

Then query builder return relation exactly for this entry, not for all;

Answer (score 0):

You can add `protected $with = ['country'];` to your People's model to eager load a relationship which is the same as  `$person = People::with('country')->find(1);`

Then you can access the relation as a property `$person->country->name` also try `People::with('country')->get()` instead of `People::country()->get()`